# Apache Kafka Event source mapping retries lambda function indefinitely when retries are used within lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-lambda

I currently have a event source mapping (ESM) from Self Managed Apache Kafka that invokes a lambda function (Consumer). However, the lambda function is calling a downstream service(REST) which sometimes may have connection issues.  Due to this, I am put a retry (`resilence4j-retry`) around the logic that invokes downstream. The idea is to retry the downstream for maximum 10 minutes with exponential back off and when retries are exhausted push the message to DLQ topic (kafka dlq) and return success response back from lambda such that the next message from Kafka topic is processed.

But even when the lambda returns a success response after the exhausted retries.  The lambda is invoked for same message again and again.  It looks like the ESM is retrying the message forever and our DLQ topic is flooded with same message.

I tried reducing the retries to only once where the lambda returns immediately after pushing the message to DLQ topic. But still lambda is invoked with same message.

Has anyone experienced this issue before. I am following it up AWS but still no solution found. Request our stack overflow members to help me out with this.

Thanks.

1. Publish a message to a kafka Topic A
2. AWS ESM takes the messages and invokes a lambda function.
3. Lambda function processes the message and invokes another downstream service.
4. Downstream returns a connection error.
5. The method that invokes the downstream is enclosed with  resilience4j @Retry and hence the downstream call is invoked again and again for 10 minutes.
6. After 10 minutes, the message is pushed to another kafka topic (DLQ topic) and the lambda returns a success response.

**Expected behaviour:**
ESM should commit the current message offset and pick up the next one and process it.

**Actual Behaviour:**
ESM invokes lambda with same message again and again. Even reducing the retry to only once doesn't work.

Comment: Update: I have done further testing on this by removing my functional code and replaced it with just a Thread.Sleep(ms).  What i observed is if the sleep time in lambda is more than 5 minutes the events from kafka topic are retried again and again even though lambda returns successfully. My lambda timeout is set to max at 15 min.  But still the messages are retried when the lambda function takes more then 5 minutes to complete.

Comment: Reported this to AWS and they acknowledge it. They provided fix to this issue today. Will perform tests again to see this is not occuring.

Comment: Its all good now after the fix.